# Как правильно связать таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица 1. Она служит для заказов:

```
ID|Kniga_id|Model_id
```

Есть таблица 2. Она служит для информации по книге.

Model - текстовая инфа.

```
ID|Price|Model|Autor|
```

Как связать эти таблицы, чтобы отобразить данные этой книги в заказе? Ее модель, автора.

Просто я передаю в таблицу заказов айди(книгу, которую купили), а в другой таблице мне надо вывести данные об этой книге. Как-то так.
Когда я нажимаю на "купить", то записывается в таблицу 1 Kniga_id номер книги, который находится в таблице 2.
При выводе информации у меня показывает только ID

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN table2 on Table2.Model = table1.Model_ID
```

http://prntscr.com/79xhh6 cейчас так. А хочется, чтобы выводило модель и автора

Comment: Просто укажите в `select` поля, которые хотите вывести.... или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я выводил id )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что надо связывать не по выбранному наугад полю, а по тому, которое *логически* соответствует полю в первой таблице. Не говоря уже о том, что связываемые колонки должны быть одного типа, и числовую никогда не связывают с текстовой.

Если нам надо установить связь с таблицей **kniga**, то какое поле подойдет больше - **Kniga**_id или Model_id?
И если у нас есть поле **kniga_id** и таблица **kniga** с полями **ID**, Price, Model и Autor, то какое поле больше всего подойдет для связывания? Неужели "Model - текстовая инфа"?

LEFT JOIN здесь так же не нужен, надо оставить обычный.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Теперь всё шикарно выводится